# Excel macro:Finding a value in an entire worksheet and clearing that value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of csv files. All I need is a code to search the entire worksheet to find the value of -999.999 in any cell and then clear that cell. Not delete but clear. SO it won't affect the calculations.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> Then Type `-999.999` then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Next press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Alternatively if you only want to replace the first instance of `-999.999` then do the same as above but instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

If for some reason you really need this in code it is a simple one line function to replace all:

```
Cells.Replace What:="-999.999", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

To repalce only the first instance it would be as follows:

```
Cells.Find(What:="-999.999", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Replace What:="-999.999", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```